# DesignSurface and Zoom

Tags: winforms, zooming, design-surface

I am trying to implement Zoom feature on a DesignSurface, which uses .Net 2 based Designer time architecture. 
I have two approaches to handle ZoomChanged event:

1. Unload the Design surface and reload with Zoomed content.
2. Identify the affected properties and set them to Zoomed values of properties.

Problem: 
 In approach 1, Unload and Reload is quite a task for run-time and would unload and reload lot of properties which would not be affected by zoom change.

In approach 2, The properties being changed would raise lot of PropertyChanged events and execute relative handlers, which would make response quite slow. If, I want to unsubscribe and resubscribe all the event handlers, I would not have any single place to do it as it spans over lot of dependent components.

Any one at rescue?